# Angular - Disable Button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, material-design

```
<div id="home-container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="true">This is a button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <ac-map></ac-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

Environment:

- Angular 10
- Chrome/Firefox (Incognito mode)

Hi guys,

I'm experiencing some undesirable behaviour when displaying my angular project. The above example shows a simple component with a button that is disabled by default (I'm using 'true' as a placeholder for a variable). When I load the component the button should be disabled. HOWEVER. When the component is loaded the button is enabled for the first second or two and then is disabled - making it look disorganised. How can I avoid this?

Kind regards,
Scott.

Comment: Try this  <button mat-raised-button disabled>This is a button</button>

Comment: so it's take 1 or 2 second time that is main issues right ?

Comment: @DarshanMalani Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how you're using the "disabled" HTML attribute thats how exactly it will behave

> The component is loaded the button is enabled for the first second or
> two and then is disabled - making it look disorganised.

Now let me briefly tell you something about the "disabled" HTML attribute first before I show you the right way, so that you won't repeat your mistake.

The “disabled” attribute of the button tag originates from HTML not angular. The main purpose of its introduction is to provide an easy way for users to interact with the buttons on web page. For example, when a user sees an inactive button on the page, he or she will never border clicking it, and this is a very good user experience.
Mostly you will see this tag used in a way like…

```
  <button disabled>Click</button>
```

The hack is to just include the attribute or not in a plain HTML. the absence of it means the button element is not disable whiles it present does the opposite. So below code will all make the button element disable even though they have different true & false value assign to them.

```
<button disabled="true">Click 1</button>
<button disabled="false">Click 2</button>
```

But in [angular you can disable buttons](https://tutorialscamp.com/angular-disable-button/) with the help of property binding, we can achieve this feature by doing something like:

```
<button class="primary" [disabled]="true">Submit</button>
```

Now, back to your question:

> HOWEVER. When the component is loaded the button is enabled for the first second or two and then is disabled - making it look disorganised. How can I avoid this?

I tried your code and is correct. So the problem could likely be related to a library that is having effect on your button.
But if you find no library, then use css to hide the button. Then within the component file. show the button element after the a timeout.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34375835)

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, I suggest you read the document about the component lifecycle of Angular. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Please check this out for a live sample.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * @title Basic buttons
 */
@Component({
  selector: "button-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "button-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["button-overview-example.css"]
})
export class ButtonOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  disabled = true;
  toggle() {
    this.disabled = !this.disabled;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggle-angular-material-button-sample?file=src/app/button-overview-example.html

In this sample, I used the variable `disabled` to indicate the button state, and implemented the `OnInit` hook which I change `false` to `true`.